# Populating an array from a JSON during a promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, promise

I am trying to wrap my head around promises and have some issues.
I have a JSON array consisting of many entries:

```
  { "Work Date"  : "08/04/2021"
  , "Work type"  : "Working"
  , "Project"    : "Projectname"
  , "Client"     : "Company"
  , "Employee"   : "John Doe"
  , "Work hours" : "2.5"
  , "Work note"  : "Work notations here"
  , "Task"       : ""
  , "Task Name"  : ""
  , "TaskType"   : ""
  },
```

In particular am interested to extract the employees to an array. So I can present / format easier.
This is my dataProvider Service (Angular) which loads the JSON and provides the data for further usage:

```js
export class DataproviderService {
  effortsList:Effort[]
  employeeList:string[]
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getData(){
    return this.http.get<any>("assets/data.json")
    .toPromise()
    .then(res => <Effort[]>res.data)
    .then(data => { 
      data.forEach(employee => this.employeeList.push(employee["Employee"]))
      return this.effortsList = data.slice();
     })
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working as I imagined. I get an uncaught error:

**Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.employeeList is undefined**

What am I doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You forgot to initlalize employee list as empty array, so your push doesn't work.

Comment: sidenote: why do you define the return type from the request as `any` just to later cast it to `Effort[]`? why not just `this.http.get<Effort[]>("assets/data.json").then(({ data }) => ... )`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your `effortsList` and `employeeList` so they are both `undefined`, what means you cannot call arrays methods on them.

```js
export class DataproviderService {
  effortsList: Effort[]
  employeeList: string[]
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.effortsList = []
    this.employeeList = []
  }

  getData() {
    return this.http.get < any > ("assets/data.json")
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => < Effort[] > res.data)
      .then(data => {
        data.forEach(employee => this.employeeList.push(employee["Employee"]))
        return this.effortsList = data.slice();
      })
  }
}
```

Additionally, this line is not a good approach:

```js
data.forEach(employee => this.employeeList.push(employee["Employee"]))`
```

I suggest you to change it to this:

```js
this.employeeList = data.map(employee => employee["Employee"])
```

This way you will be sure that your will never push same items from data to your `employeeList` (e.g. If you will call `getData` twice).

Comment: Oh, you are absolutely right. How did I miss this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your `employeeList` is not initialized. You only declared it, but didn't assign a value.

You can also simplify your code when you just do

```
getData(){
  return this.http.get<any>("assets/data.json").toPromise()
    .then(res => { 
      const data = <Effort[]>res.data;
      this.employeeList = data.map(e => e.Employee);
      return this.effortsList = data.slice();
     })
  }
}
```

And also take notice, that `toPromise` is being deprecated and will be removed soon. https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated

Comment: Thanks a lot for your imput. This looks way cleaner.